# Is there a way to hide the title bar of applications?

Tags: macos

Is there anyway to hide the title bar aside from fullscreen mode?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the short answer is no.

[TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) is one of the best utilities out there for modifying the way your system appears/behaves. They do not have any options to remove the title bars from applications in general, although there is one setting to hide the title bar of windows in Quicktime X Player.

The longer answer would be for open-source applications you could potentially modify the code generating the UI.

Comment: I use iTerm2 and this is the final thing that pisses me off, How does Chrome hide it successfully :( ?

Comment: Cocoa makes it easy to remove title bars, but the application designer has to choose to do it or provide the user with that option. In iTerm2, Preferences... Profiles->Window->"Style" popup menu choose "No Title Bar"

Comment: @itsneo you can hide title bar in iTerm2 now btw, Profile->Window->Style: No Title Bar