# I want all applications show their title bar, how do I achieve this?

Tags: macos

I do not want the titlebar to disappear. Is there a solution to have it always visible? Here is the opposite wish:

[Is there a way to hide the title bar of applications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197606/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-title-bar-of-applications)

Anyone using TinkerTool? Does it achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use Fullscreen. Maximise instead.
 Opt/click the green dot, top left, instead of just clicking it.

Or double-click the title bar.

Comment: Makes no difference on latest El Capitan. The bar disappears.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong... I loathe Fullscreen so that's how I always do it.

Comment: D'oh, sorry... Opt/click, not Cmd... Or double-click the title bar. Updating answer...