on macOS can I hide the titlebar on certain apps?
For instance, I want to hide the titlebar in the Roblox app. I wonder if there's some plist setting I could add or change, or another way to hide it.


This answer (It is up to the app developer.) is still correct https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197606/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-title-bar-of-applications.
